# DynamoDB multiple requests on a single query #210

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using [dynamo-data-mapper](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-data-mapper-js) to get some data from a DynamoDB table:

```
constructor () {
    const client = new DynamoDB({
        region: 'eu-west-1',
        endpoint: dynamoDBUrl,
        httpOptions: { timeout: 10000 },
    });
    this.mapper = new DataMapper({ client });
}

async myFunc(memberId: string): Promise<Model> {
    const options: QueryOptions = {
        indexName: 'indexName',
        pageSize: 1,
        scanIndexForward: true,
    };
    
    const query = this.mapper.query(Model, { foo: 'bar', foo2: 'bar2' }, options);

    for await (const result of query) {
        return result;
    }

    return null;
}
```

This runs on a lambda function once (triggered by API Gateway).

The majority of times, everything looks fine and the lambda executes very quickly.

However, sometimes the lambda takes between 30-60 seconds to execute. When checking traces in Cloudwatch, I can see there's multiple calls to this Model table, sometimes 50+ requests.

DynamoDB's default timeout is 2 minutes, but I set it to 10 seconds, so in case of failure, it should be retried sooner. But the weirdest thing is that all these requests duration average is around 10-20ms, so it doesn't seem it's failing.

I can't see anything wrong in the code, just wondering if there is something I don't know about dynamodb-data-mapper...

Comment: Is it a table with provisioned throughput? You might be running into ProvisionedThroughput Exceeded Exceptions and it's doing exponential backoff.

Comment: it's not, no. I believe it has to do with the number of records that sometimes it's querying and the pagination logic...

Answer (score 0):

The table has a lot of records, dynamo can only load 1MB in each request... It has to do with pagination

Comment: When using DynamoDB I always check whether or not the response includes a lastKey, if so, I do the same query again with the included lastKey in a loop. That way you wont have to worry about paginating when your application grows.
It should be a common pattern, but somehow must examples miss this. 

Also Dynamo is not "made" for these sort of huge number of query results, so it's most certainly an underlying design issue you have. Dynamo is best when queries return a small number of times. So it's quick and snappy.

Cheers.